# TypeError: spy.mockReturnValue is not a function with jest and Angular (nx)

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs, nomachine-nx

I have this test:

```
  it('should display user email', () => {
    const header = fixture.debugElement;
    const spy = jest.spyOn(localStorage, 'getItem');
    spy.mockReturnValue('test@test.com');
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(header.query(By.css(".user-label")).nativeElement.innerText).toContain("test@test.com");
  })
```

When running it shows the following error:
`TypeError: spy.mockReturnValue is not a function`

I'm using NX version 14.5.2, which already comes with Jest (27.5.1) and Angular 14.0.2

Comment: somebody had the same problem https://github.com/swc-project/jest/issues/95

Comment: I fixed it using localStore.__proto__